# How to read a file between two points in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file that looks kind of like this:

```
junk stuff NAME Test File Name VER 2.00 DATE 1/2/12 END useless stuff
```

Another one:

```
waste material NAME Test file 2 VER 1.78 DATE 1/8/13 END don't look at me, NOTREAL
```

How can I parse it so I get 3 values: name, version, and date?

Comment: Kind of like this is not helpful. What exactly will it look like? If you can't provide an exact sample then show a recurring pattern.

Comment: Can you not just split it and then access your elements ?

Comment: From your question, it looks like the answer is just to pull out columns 2,4,6,  but I suspect there is more to your question than that.

Comment: Maybe by using regexp on each line ?

Comment: The exact regular expression that you use will depend on the particular requirements, but the general idea that people have posted of using regular expressions to extract what you are interested in is a good one.  For example: can there be multiple spaces between the tag NAME and the value?  If we had "NAME<space><space>Test", would you want the resulting name to be "<space>Test" or "Test"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the line into a string than use some regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r'NAME (.+) VER (.+) DATE (.+)', 'NAME Test VER 2.00 DATE 1/2/12')
[('Test', '2.00', '1/2/12')]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re
line = 'NAME Test VER 2.00 DATE 1/2/12'
s = re.search(r'NAME (.+) VER (.+) DATE (.+)', line)
name = s.group(1)
version = s.group(2)
date = s.group(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution that doesn't depend on key names and their order

```
s = 'NAME Test VER 2.00 DATE 1/2/12'
args = s.split(' ')

vars = {}
for i in xrange(0, len(args), 2):
  vars[args[i]] = args[i+1]

print vars # {'DATE': '1/2/12', 'VER': '2.00', 'NAME': 'Test'}
```